# Keeping container alive with Docker Python SDK

Tags: python, docker

I am using the Docker Sdk for Python to run my container.

I am trying to start a docker container, and then run a command using the api exec_run (I need the exit code). 
The exec_run needs to be executed on a started container.

This is my code:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run('e7d8452ce5f5', command="echo starting", detach=True)
container.exec_run("echo execute command")
```

This raises an exception:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 409 Client Error: Conflict ("Container b65acd40f589819f490564dcb4e25f3055d85712cb7b2834ede5f2c4d57f2da6 is not running")
```

I tried running with no command when invoking client.containers.run, same exception..

Seems the container exists when the command is finished, even though in their documentation it is stated that the command run with detach=True is same as the cli docker run -d (when using docker run -d the container stays alive)

Any ideas on how to keep the container alive in order to call exec_run on it?

Comment: Your container stops because the command you use, i.e. `echo starting` doesn't keep running. Why don't you try with a command like `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: ...or just launching the container with the actual command you want to run?

Comment: Tried running sh -- same thing happens

Comment: I can't launch it with the actual command because I need the exit code and run doesn't return it.. Only exec_run

Comment: If you try with `sh` you also need to use the `-t` and `-i` options of the `docker run` command. Not using them will make `sh` exit immediately too.

Comment: Thanks! that works (with tty=True)

Answer (score 4):

When you use containers.run() method to start a ontainer,you should use **tty** parameter and set **tty=True** and then it will keep the container alive.

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run('xxxx', command="/bin/bash", tty=True,detach=True)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I am still getting error 409. Any thoughts why?