# python docker sdk how to run multiple commands in containers.run

Tags: python, docker, backend, devops, dockerpy

I am using python 3 with docker sdk and using 
`containers.run` in order to create a container and run my code 
when I use command argument with one command as a string it works fine

see code

```
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(image=image, command="echo 1")
```

When I try to use a list of commands (which is fine according to the docs)

```
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(image=image, command=["echo 1", "echo 2"])
```

I am getting this error

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container
>   process caused "exec: \"echo 1\": executable file not found in $PATH

same happens when using one string as such

```
"echo 1; echo 2"
```

I am using ubuntu 19 with docker

> Docker version 18.09.9, build 1752eb3

It used to work just fine with a list of commands, is there anything wrong with the new version of docker or am i missing something here?

Comment: the command accepts string or list, you can pass both eighter string or list. with the string you can try `client.containers.run("alpine:latest", command='sh -c "echo 1 && echo 2"')` https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use this.

```
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(image=image, command='/bin/sh')
result = container.exec_run('echo 1')
result = container.exec_run('echo 2')
   
container.stop()
container.remove()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You could improve the quality of your answer with a few explanations.

Comment: This only works when the image doesn't close automatically. If it does, then this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623344/9698467

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
container = client.containers.run(image="alpine:latest", command=["/bin/sh", "-c", 'echo 1 && echo 2'])
```

Comment: I need a method of performing a list of commands, this was a simple example of the problem, but I need to be able to use a longer list and more complex commands than echo... The API states that this should be possible

Comment: Can you post a full example for using bin bash with who commands?

Comment: `whoami` is in the path in alpine image so `container = client.containers.run(image="alpine:latest", command=['whoami'])` will work

Comment: working with whoami but not working with echo... I need to be able to run more advanced scripts than whoami unfortunately

Comment: Then you need to create a script and set it as you command in your image. As you normally do in pure docker setup

Comment: What am i missing here? the docs clearly offer an option of using a list of commands

Comment: @thebeancounter: You're missing the fact that it does not offer a list of commands, but a list that is *one* command.